# Get value of Checkbox in react custom checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I have this dynamic checkbox, that I want to update the state with the selected options only ,I tried to add some checks to filter the state on change , but it seems I am not seeing what went wrong!

```
const checkBoxesOptions = [
    { id: 1, title: 'serviceOne' },
    { id: 2, title: 'serviceTwo' },
    { id: 3, title: 'serviceThree' },
];

const [selectedCheckBoxes, setSelectedCheckBoxes] = React.useState([]);

{checkBoxesOptions.map((checkBox, i) => (
                    <CheckBox
                        key={i}
                        label={checkBox.title}
                        value={1}
                        checked={false}
                        onChange={value => {
                            let p = {
                                title: checkBox.title,
                                isTrue: value,
                            };
                            if (p.isTrue) {
                                const tempstate = selectedCheckBoxes.filter(
                                    checkbox => checkbox !== checkBox.title
                                );
                                console.log('temp state', tempstate);
                                setSelectedCheckBoxes([...selectedCheckBoxes, p.title]);
                            }

        
                            console.log(p);
                        }}
                    />
                ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `value` parameter is the event object.

```
(event) => {
    const value = event.target.checked
    <... Rest of the code ...>
  }
```

Comment: Hi Cody! thanks! according to their docs , the value is boolean , https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-custom-checkbox

Comment: The value parameter in your code is actually the event object, you can get the boolean with the above code.

Comment: it gave me undefined

Comment: I recomend console.log'ing the event object and see what it is

Comment: Yeah I did! so this library I am using https://github.com/LarvenLLC/react-custom-checkbox you can't get the value event only checked value out of the box

Comment: my issued is not getting the value, I am trying to keep recored of the checked one in react state, but I can't updated it correctly